# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use a component :

```
const data: any[] = []

<Tiers data={data}/>
```

My component is built like this:

```
const Tiers = ({
   data,
   }: {
    data?: any;
}) => {

    console.log('data', data?.length!);
    if(!data.length) return undefined;

};

export default Tiers;
```

I get the following message automatically  :

```
'Tiers' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'undefined' is not a valid JSX element.
```

Comment: So what's your question? The message seems pretty clear on what the problem is and therefore what you should change - Tiers currently _isn't_ a valid component.

Comment: At this point, I don't understand why I get this error message, the data array is an empty array and not undefined

Comment: It's not complaining about the array being undefined... (but also `data?: any` is a _terrible_ type for it, give TS the information it needs to actually help you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
return null
```

instead of

```
return undefined
```

to make `Tiers` a valid JSX component.

You need two return statements in the component like below:

```
const Tiers = ({
   data,
   }: {
    data?: any;
}) => {

    console.log('data', data?.length!);
    if(!data.length) return null;
    return null
};

export default Tiers;
```

Comment: the error message changes to :

'Tiers' cannot be used as a JSX component.                                        
  Its return type 'null | undefined' is not a valid JSX element.                                 
    The type 'undefined' is not assignable to the type 'Element | null'. 

if I use return null

Comment: Why would you _conditionally_ return the same thing in both cases?

Comment: @timothe, please use English as the language when commenting. You need two returns in your code. Check the updated answer!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, actually shouldn't be doing it. I just wanted to clear the error @timothe gets. Should return some valid jsx. I didn't use `return data` since I don't know what's inside it if it's jsx elements then fine

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems,

1. It needs at least one condition that returns a JSX.Element(even a very simple one like Hello), if not, you probably needed a function instead.
2. A component cannot return undefined. If you want it to return nothing, you should return null instead of undefined.